# How to bin the continuous variables based on the binary "Outcome"(0,1) , bin should have at least 5% of "1" of Outcome

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Python Pandas: How to discretize(bin) the continuous variables (A and B) based on the binary variable "Outcome" (0,1). The maximum number of bins should be 5 and each variables bin should have at least 5% of category "1" of Outcome variable.

i am able to bin the variables using the pandas function qcut or cut, but the i am not getting an idea that how to put the 5% condition while binning each numerical variable.

for example:

```
bin               total cnt 0's count   1's count
(0.92, 1.481]       100       80           20
(0.472, 0.92]       100       70           30
(-0.248, 0.472]     100       60           40
(-0.53, -0.248]     100       90           10
(-1.208, -0.53]     100       100           0
```

The last bin does not have any count for 1 and it does not satisfy the rule of 5%, in this case bin has to created to satisfy 5% condition for 5 bins or lesser than 5 bins.

I have given a sample code i created to bin the data using qcut but i am lacking in the logic of 5%.

i would be great if anyone help me on this question, also i have more than 1000 variables to bin and i need to put the condition to apply the binning for each variable. Also please let me know the main difference between "qcut" and "cut" function in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from random import randint, choice

np.random.seed(1001)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(25, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])

df['Outcome'] = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(25)]

df['A_Bin'] = pd.qcut(df["A"], 5)
df['B_Bin'] = pd.qcut(df["B"], 5)
```

df:

```
     A           B       Outcome       A_Bin           B_Bin
0   -1.086446   -0.896065   0   (-1.208, -0.53]     (-1.465, -0.811]
1   -0.306299   -1.339934   0   (-0.53, -0.248]     (-1.465, -0.811]
2   -1.206586   -0.641727   1   (-1.208, -0.53]     (-0.811, -0.0992]
3   1.307946    1.845460    0   (0.92, 1.481]       (0.984, 1.845]
4   0.829115    -0.023299   0   (0.472, 0.92]       (-0.0992, 0.984]
5   -0.208564   -0.916620   0   (-0.248, 0.472]     (-1.465, -0.811]
6   -1.074743   -0.086143   0   (-1.208, -0.53]     (-0.0992, 0.984]
7   1.175839    -1.635092   0   (0.92, 1.481]       (-2.213, -1.465]
8   1.228194    1.076386    0   (0.92, 1.481]       (0.984, 1.845]
9   0.394773    -0.387701   0   (-0.248, 0.472]     (-0.811, -0.0992]
10  0.588402    -1.433299   0   (0.472, 0.92]       (-1.465, -0.811]
11  -0.323575   1.252985    0   (-0.53, -0.248]     (0.984, 1.845]
12  -0.730743   1.428485    0   (-1.208, -0.53]     (0.984, 1.845]
13  0.944654    -0.264003   1   (0.92, 1.481]       (-0.811, -0.0992]
14  -0.163213   -0.964107   0   (-0.248, 0.472]     (-1.465, -0.811]
15  -0.342647   0.048904    0   (-0.53, -0.248]     (-0.0992, 0.984]
16  -0.499632   -2.211905   1   (-0.53, -0.248]     (-2.213, -1.465]
17  0.309837    -1.589651   1   (-0.248, 0.472]     (-2.213, -1.465]
18  0.729455    -0.107901   1   (0.472, 0.92]       (-0.811, -0.0992]
19  -0.650171   -1.693057   0   (-1.208, -0.53]     (-2.213, -1.465]
20  -0.368474   -1.590372   1   (-0.53, -0.248]     (-2.213, -1.465]
21  1.480506    0.474440    1   (0.92, 1.481]       (-0.0992, 0.984]
22  0.913864    0.960470    1   (0.472, 0.92]       (-0.0992, 0.984]
23  0.084543    1.717231    0   (-0.248, 0.472]     (0.984, 1.845]
24  0.851893    -0.754885   1   (0.472, 0.92]       (-0.811, -0.0992]
```

Count:

```
df['Outcome'].value_counts()

Outcome Count
 0       16
 1        9
```

Comment: When I do `df.groupby('A_Bin').count()` I see the data is evenly split.  I guess I'm not clear what the problem is.  Also, you use both numpy.random and random.  Both need their own seed.

Comment: I have given a dummy data to show the problem. I want to bin the continuous Var but each bin should have atleast 5% of Outcome of category 1.

Comment: how did you produce the first dataframe in the post?  When I bin things I see at least 5%.

Comment: The first example is also a dummy one show that one of the bin is not having 5% of category 1. My real data has 50k rows and 1000 columns. When binning I need to make sure each Binned variable gets at least 5% of category 1